# passing multiple arguments to a python function from bash (in variables)

Tags: python, bash, function, shell

I wrote a python function called `plot_ts_ex` that takes two arguments `ts_file` and `ex_file` (and the file name for this function is `pism_plot_routine`). I want to run this function from a bash script from terminal.
When I don't use variables in the bash script in pass the function arguments (in this case `ts_file = ts_g10km_10ka_hy.nc` and `ex_file = ex_g10km_10ka_hy.nc`) directly, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
python -c 'import pism_plot_routine; pism_plot_routine.plot_ts_ex("ts_g10km_10ka_hy.nc", "ex_g10km_10ka_hy.nc")'
```

which is similar as in [Run function from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987041/run-function-from-the-command-line), that works.

But when I define variables for the input arguments, it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh 
ts_name="ts_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
ex_name="ex_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
python -c 'import pism_plot_routine; pism_plot_routine.plot_ts_ex("$ts_name", "$ex_name")'
```

It gives the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'$ts_name'
```

Then I found a similar question [passing an argument to a python function from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939713/passing-an-argument-to-a-python-function-from-bash/47943114#47943114?newreg=8641b85190ae44d7ad69a8b2b32f61f8) for a python function with only one argument and I tried

```
#!/bin/sh
python -c 'import sys, pism_plot_routine; pism_plot_routine.plot_ts_ex(sys.argv[1])' "$ts_name" "$ex_name"
```

but that doesn't work.

So how can I pass 2 arguments for a python function in a bash script using variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use single quotes the variables aren’t going to be expanded, you should use double quotes instead:

```
#!/bin/sh 
ts_name="ts_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
ex_name="ex_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
python -c "import pism_plot_routine; pism_plot_routine.plot_ts_ex('$ts_name', '$ex_name')"
```

---

You can also use sys.argv, arguments are stored in a list, so `ts_name` is `sys.arv[1]` and `ex_name` is `sys.argv[2]`:

```
#!/bin/sh 
ts_name="ts_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
ex_name="ex_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
python -c 'import sys, pism_plot_routine; pism_plot_routine.plot_ts_ex(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])' "$ts_name" "$ex_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are giving the value `$ts_name` to python as string, bash does not do anything with it. You need to close the `'`, so that it becomes a string in bash, and then open it again for it to become a string in python.

The result will be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh 
ts_name="ts_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
ex_name="ex_g10km_10ka_hy.nc" 
python -c 'import pism_plot_routine; pism_plot_routine.plot_ts_ex("'$ts_name'", "'$ex_name'")'
```

For issues like this it is often nice to use some smaller code to test it, I used `python3 -c 'print("${test}")'` to figure out what it was passing to python, without the bother of the `pism_plot`.